# Link to list all apps by a developer in iPhone's App Store

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, itunes

I'm adding links in my game so players can rate and see more games of the same developer.

For rating I'm using

```
itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/idMY_GAME_ID_IN_NUMBERS
```

and it works properly, opening the App Store straight away.

However, I can't find a link that opens the App Store app in my iPhone and shows a list of all games by the same developer.

I've tried this

```
http://appstore.com/STUDIO_NAME
```

and it works, but it opens first the device web browser and then the App Store, I guess because of the *http* protocol instead of *itms-apps*. I'd rather going straight to the App Store like the *rate* link does.

Any idea about how to achieve it?

Comment: I've added another answer since I think ViralSavaj's answer is out of date. Mine is a lot simpler too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For view Application page :

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"itms://itunes.apple.com/us/app/APPNAME/idApp?mt=8&uo=4"]];
//APPNAME = Application name, idApp = Application unique id
```

For view App from the developer

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"itms://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/DEVNAME/idDEVID?uo=4"]];
 DEVNAME = Developer name in small chars, idDEVID = developer id, you can get it from iTunes.
```

**Update 1**

If you have your App Id then you can get your developer id like,

```
https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=YourAnyAppID
```

Run this in web browser, and in response search for `artistViewUrl` word, this will give you `URL`, that **List all APPs from Same Developer**

Just keep in mind that replace `http` to `itms` to stop redirection.

**Update 2**

List all app of a developer , from: `appstore.com/{developername}`.

Get our single app link, from: `appstore.com/appname`. You can get this things when app get published.

May this helps.

HTH, Enjoy Coding!!

Comment: I got rid of the mt and uo parameters (not required AFAIK) and works like a charm. Thanks!

However, as I haven't published my game yet I can't get my developer id from iTunes Store (I'm testing with a different studio). How can I get it? Anywhere in iTunes Connect?

Comment: This may not possible, coz for posting your game, you need to submit on app store, for that, you must need Apple id, You can join apple Dev program, and that way you can get your dev app id.

Comment: Yes I know, I'm already an iOS developer and have access to the iTunes Connect and all that stuff. What I am asking is where to find the dev id. I have the app id but not the dev id. Do you know where can I see it?

Comment: if you have submitted a single app to app store, you can open it web browser like this, `https://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/twitter-inc./id296415947`, here `twitter-inc.` is Company/Developer Name with replace space with -, and suffix `id296415947` is the developer id, so you can post it like    `itms://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/twitter-inc./id296415947`

Comment: I don't have any game submitted yet, this will be the first one. However, I'm already enrolled to the iOS developer program and I'd like to know where I can get my DEV ID before submitting any app, as I need it in order to use it in the game.

Comment: Have you got your App ID?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75574/discussion-between-viral-savaj-and-jgg).

Comment: Hey there, pretty sure your answer is out of date. I made my own answer down below which works today, it's also a bunch simpler!

Answer (score 1):

It's really simple to link to the list of a developer's iOS apps or a single iOS app.

**Link to all of a developer's apps, in list form:** `appstore.com/developername` so since my apps show up as by Henry Stern you can find my apps at [appstore.com/henrystern](https://appstore.com/henrystern).

**Link to a single app:** `appstore.com/appname` so since one of my apps is named "NoteFlow—one note for life" you can find it at [appstore.com/noteflow—onenoteforlife](https://appstore.com/noteflow%E2%80%94onenoteforlife).

If you want the full long link to an app or your own classic "Available on the App Store" banner you can find that at the official [iTunes Link Maker](https://linkmaker.itunes.apple.com/en-us).