# Getting App Store URL before Apple Review

Tags: ios, app-store

Is it possible to generate an App Store URL, in the beta testing phase of the app, before Apple Reviews the app? I would like to have a link in my app, to my app in the App Store, which users can share with their friends. I would like to have this available in the beta testing phase. Can one only add this link after it  has been accepted ? Does that imply that it is always added in a revision after the first ?

Comment: Just go through the **Update1** of this [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29696907/link-to-list-all-apps-by-a-developer-in-iphones-app-store/29697025#29697025)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i give app store link in my apps before approving another apps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513945/how-can-i-give-app-store-link-in-my-apps-before-approving-another-apps)

Comment: Duplicate question. Have you not researched this at all prior to posting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes its possible to create a App URL after registering the application on iTunes Connect.**This doen't mean your application is live on Apple Store, you just submitted required data to iTunes connect, so unique id got generated & you can use that to create URL.**

Once you register application on iTunes connect one unique ID for your application will be generated. And you can create your App URL like below format.

`https://itunes.apple.com/[countrycode]/app/[YOUR APP NAME]/[YOUR UNIQUE APP ID]?mt=8`

But in beta testing it will not work, You will get error message because the application is not available in App Store.

Once application become live it will work absolutely fine.

**Note : Once you register the application on iTunes connect you need to upload at least first version within 90 days else others will be eligible to use that name.**

Comment: Thank you for this note. The key point is that I need it for Beta Testing. I tried methods to obtain links but always came across the error message that you reference. Whether I use any of the link templates :* https://itunes.apple.com/[countrycode]/app/[YOUR APP NAME]/[YOUR UNIQUE APP ID]?mt=8 *http://www.itunes.com/app/AppName""http://itunes.apple.com/app/id<app_apple_id>" , I get an error message. The http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513945/how-can-i-give-app-store-link-in-my-apps-before-approving-another-apps does not solve my problem, and it doesn't have an accepted answer.

Comment: @stackQA, Once your application become live it will work perfectly.. Its because your application is not live on Apple store.. You just registered the application on iTunes connect.. Let the application become live & then see.. Hope this make sense to you..

Comment: @stackQA I already have mentioned that this will not work in beta testing.. Also mentioned that you will get alert message.. Read the answer fully & carefully...

Comment: You are perfectly correct. My comment was not clear. The intention of the comment was in support of your answer and to highlight that I have in fact tried various methods, and done some research before posting the question.

Comment: The url of a live app I have doesn't follow this format, it is: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/theid. There is no app name part to it.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can get your app's App Store URL through iTunes Connect.

Navigate to My Apps > [the app whose link you want], then under More, you'll see "View on App Store". Right click that and copy the link.

[image: Screenshot]

This should give you something like this:

```
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/[APP NAME]/[APP ID]?ls=1&mt=8
```

I've noticed that removing the `/us` (or whatever country code it defaults to for you) makes the URL universal, and iTunes is smart enough to detect the store.

Answer (score 5):

Find App ID= My Apps -> App Store -> App Information -> General Information -> Apple ID

Then your store url is below

```
https://apps.apple.com/app/id[AppId]
```

like this 
https://apps.apple.com/app/id1513329198