# List all apps under a same account on Play/AppStore

Tags: android, ios, google-play, itunes-store

Is there any API provided by Google or Apple which allows listing of apps published from my developer account. say if I published 10apps, the api should be able to return me list of those 10apps.

Does anyone know?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29696907/link-to-list-all-apps-by-a-developer-in-iphones-app-store

Answer (score 1):

There should be a way with gsutil.  can you check out http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2015/04/integrate-play-data-into-your-workflow.html